How to get method annotation field values
My Controller Class is this:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/admin")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "E-Commerce Application")
public class AddressController {
    
    @Autowired
    private AddressService addressService;
        
    @GetMapping("/addresses")
    public ResponseEntity<List<AddressDTO>> getAddresses() {
        List<AddressDTO> addressDTOs = addressService.getAddresses();
        
        return new ResponseEntity<List<AddressDTO>>(addressDTOs, HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }
}

I am trying to get 'getAddresses' method annotation "GetMapping" value "/addresses". I found while debug, the value in annotation.h.memberFields variable.
I tried, like this, it is pringing in output but how to get 'value' field in my program is become challenge.
public class ClassMethodsTool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Class<?> myClass = AddressController.class;

        Method[] methods = myClass.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            System.out.println(method);
            Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
            for (Annotation a: annotations
                 ) {
                System.out.println(method.getDeclaredAnnotations()[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}   

This pringing
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping(path={}, headers={}, name="", produces={}, params={}, value={"/addresses/{addressId}"}, consumes={})

value={"/addresses/{addressId}"} I want to get this value in program.
I tried a lot of ways even no luck. Need help.

Ignoring any exceptions:
Method method = AddressController.class.getDeclaredMethod("getAddresses");
GetMapping annotation = method.getAnnotation(GetMapping.class);
String[] paths = annotation.value();

In your existing code you can also cast the annotation to GetMapping. If you want to see what the annotation type is for any variable of type Annotation you can use annotationType(). Don't use getClass(), that will return some JDK internal class.
Adapting your code to get the paths in a fully safe way:
public class ClassMethodsTool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> myClass = AddressController.class;
        Method[] methods = myClass.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            System.out.println(method);
            Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
            for (Annotation a: annotations) {
                System.out.println(a);
                if (a.annotationType() == GetMapping.class) {
                    GetMapping getMapping = (GetMapping) a;
                    String[] paths = getMapping.value();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I suggest to try print out Annotation's value and that would look like that:
public class ClassMethodsTool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Class<?> myClass = AddressController.class;

        Method[] methods = myClass.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method method : methods) {
            System.out.println(method);
            Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
            for (Annotation a: annotations) {
                System.out.println(a.value());
            }
        }
    }
} 

